# What is the VPN icon in the menu bar?

Tags: macos, vpn, menu-bar

I have long wondered what the significance of the VPN icon in the menu bar is:

[image: vpn icon]

Anyone know?

Edit:

I think people are misunderstanding my question.  It is the icon for the built-in OSX VPN.  I use it regularly.  My question is what the icon itself represents.  A padlock?  A tunnel? A spaceship?

Comment: Not sure. Click around. Is it from a program you installed or an OS X built-in feature? You may find this site useful: http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/customizing-the-os-x-menu-bar--mac-49391

Comment: I don't think people understand your question. I have always wondered the same thing! I don't think it represents anything but am not sure.

Comment: As you can see, people get confused about questions that can be summarized as "That thing I just explained - Why did Apple do that?" Have a peek at [help] and feel free to edit this to make a practical case as to why you need to know the answer or how it affects you getting something done that's on-topic and we can reopen this.

Comment: @bmike you're right, I have no practical need to know this - just a long standing curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few people think it's an RSA SecurID tag:

- [Tribe](https://web.archive.org/web/20150822122529/http://osx.tribe.net:80/thread/1ba4a52c-807c-4c6f-bf73-5561bcc208ed)
- [MacTalk](https://web.archive.org/web/20150722054302/http://www.mactalk.com.au:80/11/58913-what-does-vpn-menubar-icon-mean.html)

Don't know if I buy it though.

Comment: Still not a 100% answer, but this does seem most likely.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the file is at `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/VPN.menu/Contents/Resources/VPN0.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

It is what it says it is - a VPN (virtual private network) indicator. I use it every day to connect to the office. The VPN gives me a secure, encrypted tunnel through a potentially insecure public network (like a cafe or airport).

That indicator changes when you're connected, and optionally you see how long you've been connected alongside it.

This is only for Apple's built-in VPN; there are others like Cisco AnyConnect, that use different encryption protocols; those don't use that icon. You must have a VPN set up on your computer for that to appear (SystemPreferences->Network, in the left hand column)

Answer (score 0):

If you have zoom turned on and zoom in real tight on that icon, it does -in a vague sort of way-, look like one of those RSA SecureID tokens that some companies pass out